# Why does jQuery complete the tags on its own

Tags: jquery

I am trying to encapsulate the  tag with the other div tags with classes **A** and **B**. Here's what my final result should look like:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
      **<div class="C"></div>**
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the following code to do it:

```
<script>
    jQuery('<div class="A"><div class="B">').insertBefore('.C');
    jQuery('</div></div>').insertAfter('.C');
            </script>
```

However, the code comes out as:

```
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="C">
</div>
```

This is clearly not what I intended. Please help.

Comment: jQuery methods don't work with html. Any method that takes html will parse it into a DOM subtree independently and then work with that.

Answer (score 4):

[`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) is the function you need, since you want to *wrap* two `div` tags around an existing one, instead of inserting new tags before or after it:

```
$('.C').wrap('<div class="A"><div class="B"></div></div>');
```

Comment: +1 works nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/sYPYS/, checking elements after execution show the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `wrap()` method:

> Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('.C').wrap('<div class="A"><div class="B"></div></div>');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fzh52/5/)

<sub>Note that `jQuery('</div></div>').insertAfter('.C');` does not generate html tags.</sub>

---

My answer has one downvote from an anonymous downvoter, surely because I had used `$('.C').wrap('<div class="A"/>')` and a commenter also said that it's broken. Here is the part of [`jQuery documention`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Using `.wrap()`, we can insert an HTML structure around the inner `<div>` elements like so:

```
$('.inner').wrap('<div class="new" />');
```

The new `<div>` element is *created on the fly and added to the DOM*. The result is a new `<div>` wrapped around each matched element:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for fiddle and adding explanation on why OP's code did not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have looked for the wrap() function. This solved my problem!

Comment: Please fix the html, what you are doing is `$('.C').wrap('<div class="A"><div class="B"></div></div>');` It's much less confusing if you don't rely on browser fixing your broken html.

Comment: @undefined you didn't fix it at all. It's now actually broken effectively as well. What is `/>` supposed to do? It's completely unnecessary and broken.

Comment: @Esailija I had used `<div class"A"/>` in my answer, and you said that it's broken, check the jQuery doc for the `wrap()` method and see how they suggest to use the wrapper. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: @undefined It was broken in the jsfiddle, that's what I meant. and I have not downvoted. `/>` is horrible regardless of what jQuery docs say. Especially when you have multiple elements like that, it's hard to tell what the real html will be in the eyes of the browser.

Comment: @Esailija Yes, that's correct. But I'm not sure about the eyes of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

your calls are incorrect

should be

```
<div class="C">Some Text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $(".C").wrap($("<div class='A' />")).wrap($("<div class='B' />"));​
  });
</script>
```

You didn't close in first call A class div so you left to jquery handle it as developers implement innsertAfter method.

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/kZSTu/1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/kZSTu/ Check the elements after execution, a and b divs are not added

Comment: That is becose you copy and paste code without thinking :) http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/kZSTu/1/  you should always consult API documentation http://api.jquery.com

Comment: I'm confused, the code you show in your answer doesn't work. I merely pointed that out in a fiddle. It was your code! If the code in your new fiddle works you propably should post that instead!

Comment: you are right, I will update code, but anyway, my first code was just demonstration how to use wrap function in jquery

Comment: If you are posting non-working code in your answer you should probably point that out explicitly. Most posters will try to copy-paste your answer, relying on it to work. +1 for your edit though :)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be jQuery, but rather the browser that is rendering it. I have seen Chrome's inspector render end tags where I had forgotten them in the original markup.

It seems like you actually want to use the [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

Your script would look like:

```
$('.C').wrap(function () {
  return '<div class="A"><div class="B">';
});
```

Comment: Though the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/ENDj6/ it does copy the text instead of just leaving it in the original tag, ending up duplicating it. The test manipulation isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks for checking, you're right. I misread the docs! The snippet that returns from the function will wrap the target, I'll edit.